# Check if current post is the latest (not last)

Tags: navigation

I'm having problems finding this: I'd like to create a post navigation which checks if the current post is the newest (latest). If it's the latest post it should give older posts as navigation.

I have this already working for the 'last' post:

```
<?php if( ($wp_query->current_post + 1) < ($wp_query->post_count) ) { ?>

      SHOW 5 NEWEST POSTS

<?php }; ?>
```

How do I create the check for the latest post?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Simply query for the latest post and compare IDs:

```
  function wpse110867_is_latest_post( $post_id, $query_args = array() ){
      static $latest_post_id = false;
      $post_id = empty( $post_id  ) ? get_the_ID() : $post_id ;

      if( !$latest_post_id ){
          $query_args['numberposts'] = 1;
          $query_args['post_status'] = 'publish';
          $last = wp_get_recent_posts( $query_args );
          $latest_post_id = $last['0']['ID'];
      }

      return $latest_post_id == $post_id;
  }
```

#### Example Usage

In the main query:

```
if( wpse110867_is_latest_post() ){
   echo 'This is the latest post';
}
```

To find the last post of a particular post type:

```
if( wpse110867_is_latest_post( get_the_ID(), array( 'post_type' => 'my-post-type' ) ){
   echo 'This is the latest post';
}
```

Comment: Hi Stephan, thanks for your input but it's not working.. I pasted the function in functions.php and tried the example usage in my single.php. It won't give an error or 'this is the latest post'..

Comment: Haven't been able to check it. Where's it failing? Is it finding the right post ID? Do you want the latest of any post type, or latest matching a specific query (`$query_args` is provided for that)

Comment: Ah sorry Stephan, I forgot to mention I'm viewing a custom post type called 'apps'. With the code I'm already using for the last post I didn't have to use it. I don't know if it's finding the right post ID. How can I check? (i'm not a programmer myself..)

Comment: @rwzdoom - Ok, I've updated my answer with an example for a CPT. To find the latest post just go that post's edit screen and check the url you're on. It will have `?post=[ID-of-post]`.